# Roman numerals, titletoc and hyperlinks

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, margins, titletoc, roman-numerals

My sections use roman numbers. But when they display in the TOC, the sections labels overtake on the left margin. I tried fixing it with the `dottedcontents` command but then the hyperlink disappears from the section label.

I set hyperlinks color to blue for illustration purposes.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[rightlabels]{titletoc}

%\dottedcontents{section}[1.5em]{}{1.5em}{2em}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}.}
\titleformat{\section}{\sffamily\bfseries\Large\color{red}}{\Roman{section}.}{0.15cm}{}{}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}.}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\sffamily\bfseries\large\color{red}}{\Roman{section}.\Alph{subsection}.}{0.10cm}{}{}

\usepackage[colorlinks, linkcolor=blue, unicode]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{First part}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\subsection{Third subsection}

\section{Second part}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\subsection{Third subsection}

\section{Third part}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\subsection{Third subsection}
\end{document}
```

The preview:
[image: first preview]

When I uncomment `\dottedcontents{section}[1.5em]{}{1.5em}{2em}`, it gives me this:
[image: second preview]

The labels don't overtake anymore on the left margin **but** the dots are weird, no more formatting and more importantly no more hyperlinks on the section labels. What should I do instead?

### EDIT

Replacing `\dottedcontents{section}[1.5em]{}{1.5em}{2em}` with `\titlecontents{section}[2.2em]{\addvspace{10pt}\bfseries}{\contentslabel{1.75em}}{\hspace{-1.75em}}{\hfill\contentspage}` gives me a more satisfaying result, but the hyperlink is still broken for section labels...

Here's the preview:
[image: Third preview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use package `tocbasic` instead of `titletoc`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocbasic}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[numwidth=2em]{tocline}{section,subsection}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\numberline@prefix}{\hfill}   % emulation of titletoc's
\renewcommand*{\numberline@postfix}{\enskip} % rightlabel
\makeatother


\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}.}
\titleformat{\section}{\sffamily\bfseries\Large\color{red}}{\Roman{section}.}{0.15cm}{}{}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}.}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\sffamily\bfseries\large\color{red}}{\Roman{section}.\Alph{subsection}.}{0.10cm}{}{}

\usepackage[colorlinks, linkcolor=blue, unicode]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{First part}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\subsection{Third subsection}

\section{Second part}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\subsection{Third subsection}

\section{Third part}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\subsection{Third subsection}
\end{document}
```

[image: right aligned roman section numbers and alphabetic subsection numbers in ToC]

Or without using internal commands and maybe with better indent for the subsection entries:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocbasic}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[numwidth=2em,entrynumberformat=\labelright]{tocline}{section}
\newcommand*{\labelright}[1]{\hspace*{0pt plus 1filll}#1\ }

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[indent=2em,numwidth=1.5em]{tocline}{subsection}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}.}
\titleformat{\section}{\sffamily\bfseries\Large\color{red}}{\Roman{section}.}{0.15cm}{}{}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}.}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\sffamily\bfseries\large\color{red}}{\Roman{section}.\Alph{subsection}.}{0.10cm}{}{}

\usepackage[colorlinks, linkcolor=blue, unicode]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{First part}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\subsection{Third subsection}

\section{Second part}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\subsection{Third subsection}

\section{Third part}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\subsection{Third subsection}
\end{document}
```

[image: same without internal commands]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this thorough answer! It works perfectly